# How to verify forward confirmed DNS status with a single command?

Tags: linux, dns, unix-utils

If I want to verify that an IP resolves to its DNS name and vice versa I usually run two commands. Like so...

```
$ host 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer google-public-dns-a.google.com.

$ host google-public-dns-a.google.com.
google-public-dns-a.google.com has address 8.8.8.8
google-public-dns-a.google.com has IPv6 address 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

... and then I can indeed confirm that: *"Yes, we DO have forward confirmed reverse DNS ("FCrDNS") for that IPv4 address."*

Surely somebody must have built a SINGLE utility that does that in one step.  (And therefore eliminates typos when typing the second command. And can handle DNS names that resolve to more than one IP. And can handle IPv6.)

What is that single command?

#### Related question

There is a related question for nslookup on Windows but unfortunately the accepted answer seems to be unrelated to the question. -> [*Windows nslookup: Do reverse DNS lookup in one step?*](https://superuser.com/questions/432689/windows-nslookup-do-reverse-dns-lookup-in-one-step)

Comment: Why not just make a quick bash script to do both commands?

Comment: @EBGreen: Because I bet someone has done that before/made a nice PIP module or something. (That correctly handles/verifies multiple returned records. And handles IPv4/IPv6.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, at risk of being removed as spam… the command I use is [rdt](https://nullroute.eu.org/code/rdt) which I've written myself:

[image: screenshot]

Note however that it only *displays* information, because not all services agree on how to handle edge cases such as multiple A records on the domain name, or multiple PTR records on the IP address.

Comment: Your rdt script is great. It is now my go-to tool for this. Kudos for writing this!